# Export Data on Chart to Excel/CSV LogiXML

Tags: .net, xml

I have a very simple question. I have been trying to export a set of data (2 columns) from a data-layer that is currently being used on a graph. What I am trying to accomplish is, to obtain the data enclosed in that graph and present it in an excel or csv spreadsheet as data (not the actual graph). I want to know if this is possible without creating a separate data table and linking the export to that. I have tried multiple Action.Export to accomplish this, but I am at a point where I'm not sure if it can be done.

I appreciate any help I might get. Thank you!

UPDATE:  This is the modifications I made to your report David, to recreate my issue:

```
 <Body>
<Dashboard2 SaveFile="@Function.AppPhysicalPath~\SavedDashboards\Dashboard.xml" DashboardAdjustable="True" AllowFreeformLayout="False" DashboardTabs="True">
  <Panel ID="pnl1" Caption="pnl1" MultipleInstances="True">
    <PanelContent>
      <Division ShowModes="rdExportCsv" ID="divTable" IdeDisplayStatus="Collapsed">
        <DataTable ID="table">
          <DataLayer Type="Static" ID="dlStatic1">
            <StaticDataRow columnA="Test 1" columnB="100" />
            <StaticDataRow columnA="Test 3" columnB="110" />
            <StaticDataRow columnA="Test 2" columnB="105" />
            <DataLayerLink ID="linkData" />
          </DataLayer>
          <AutoColumns />
        </DataTable>
      </Division>
      <Division ID="divChart" ShowModes="rdBrowser" IdeDisplayStatus="Collapsed">
        <Chart Type="XY" ChartDataColumn="columnB" XYChartType="Bar" ChartHeight="260" ChartWidth="400" ChartLabelColumn="columnA">
          <DataLayer Type="Linked" LinkedDataLayerID="linkData" />
        </Chart>
      </Division>
      <Button ID="ExportCSV" Caption="Export CSV" IdeDisplayStatus="Collapsed">
        <Action Type="CSV">
          <Target Type="CSV" ExportDataTableID="table" />
        </Action>
      </Button>
    </PanelContent>
  </Panel>
</Dashboard2>
```

After clicking the export button, it exports to a CSV file, but with the error I mentioned in the comments below. Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to create a separate data table to export columns as Excel or CSV.  The reason being, the Logi engine uses the column attributes to instruct the export behavior correctly (eg. width, data type, data formatting, etc).   The table you build doesn't need to be displayed in your interactive version of the report, however.   You can use "ShowModes" to show the chart during the web output, and use the table for the exported content.  Also, you can use "Linked" datalayers to populate both the table and the chart, so that your query or other data source call only needs to be executed 1 time.

Here's a simple example, using both concepts- LinkedData Layers and ShowModes

```
<Body>
  <Division ShowModes="rdExportCsv" ID="divTable">
    <DataTable ID="table">
      <DataLayer Type="Static" ID="dlStatic1">
        <StaticDataRow columnA="Test 1" columnB="100" />
        <StaticDataRow columnA="Test 3" columnB="110" />
        <StaticDataRow columnA="Test 2" columnB="105" />
        <DataLayerLink ID="linkData" />
      </DataLayer>
      <AutoColumns />
    </DataTable>
  </Division>
  <Division ID="divChart" ShowModes="rdBrowser">
    <Chart Type="XY" ChartDataColumn="columnB" XYChartType="Bar" ChartHeight="260" ChartWidth="400" ChartLabelColumn="columnA">
      <DataLayer Type="Linked" LinkedDataLayerID="linkData" />
    </Chart>
  </Division>
  <Button ID="ExportCSV" Caption="Export CSV">
    <Action Type="CSV">
      <Target Type="CSV" ExportDataTableID="table" />
    </Action>
  </Button>
</Body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That seems to be the way to go. However, my data-table is showing up fine, but no matter whether I show it or not (and include a show mode of CSV), my file keeps exporting like this:
    ï»¿     on the first row and column with nothing else!  Any ideas why this could be happening? (I've also tried Excel export but the worksheet comes out empty) BTW, I am doing this within a dashboard panel element, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I changed your report a little bit, to recreate my problem. It is the exact same code, except that it has been included in a dashboard panel. The export keeps coming out with  ï»¿  on the first column/row. Is this a bug?

Comment: If you pull it out of the dashboard panel does it work properly?   It sounds like the Request parameters or some other variables might not be getting passed into the export properly.  You might try explicitly sending the values as LinkParameters to the export action and see if that helps

Comment: Exactly! If the data tables are outside the dashboard element itself, the exporting works fine. Could this be a bug? I will try to pass the parameters like you suggested and see what happens. How would I call the data which is contained in the datalayer though?  Should a @Data.Name~ (for a 'Name' column) do?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's possible that this is a bug, however, you might check that this hasn't already been resolved in a later release (via release notes published to the Logi Dev Net site).   And, yes, you would be able to reference the values as @Data.Name~ from your table.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help David, but using LinkParameters doesn't solve the problem. Still getting a blank excel export. Any other suggestions? I really need to export this data, but I do not want to compromise the security of the report by adding it on the body (even if I'm hiding it, it will conflict with other security elements). Thank you

Comment: The best option might be to push the table and chart into a sub-report under your Dashboard panel.  That way both could be handled somewhat separately from the rest of the panel content.   This is a bit of a design change-- but would ensure that the export can work properly.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your suggestion, when adding a Sub-Report element, you must call a different Definition file, so add the table and graph in a separate definition and just include them in the sub-report?

Comment: Yes.  The subreport would contain your chart and table inside their own definition.  You can allow the subreport to blend into the dashboard by turning off the borders and other scrolling of the subreport container element

Comment: Forgot to mention, there is only one problem, the panel that contains the chart and table accepts a panel parameters element. Is there a way to pass those parameters (since the user can actively change them) and update the definition accordingly?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you may use LinkParams under your SubReport element to pass/forward these parameters to the SubReport as well.

Comment: I just tried this and I get the same error. I even created a table with those parameters being instantiated on the definition itself, displays properly on the different definition but won't export correctly. The only thing constant throughout is the fact I'm using a SP data-layer. Do you believe this could have anything to do with it? Otherwise, I'm lost!

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the current release. It doesn't matter how you present the data, if a data table element lives inside the panel, it will not export.